# Android Intent Cannot resolve constructor

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a first class extending Fragment, and a second class extending Activity.

My Fragment is working fine, and my code for the Intent in the Fragment is :

```
ImageButton button= (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyFragment.this, MyClass.class);
            MyFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);            }
    });
```

My class MyClass code is :

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // The activity is being created.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        setContentView(R.layout.MyClass);
    } 
}
```

The error is :

`Gradle: cannot find symbol constructor Intent(com.xxxx.xxxx.MyFragment,java.lang.Class<com.xxxx.xxxx.MyClass>)`

I don't know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Use

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyClass.class);
```

or

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyFragment.this.getActivity(), MyClass.class);
```

to start a new Activity. This is because you will need to pass Application or component context as a first parameter to the Intent Constructor when you are creating an Intent for a specific component of your application.

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myClass.class);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how come this is not available anywhere in the main android resources?

Comment: @Kruger Brent You should ask somebody who is responsible for the "main android resources". I don't believe they read stackoverflow or at least not on a regular basis.

Comment: It happened to me. I used the new Intent during callback block and specified the source class **this**. That's why I am going wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Or you can simply start the activity as shown below;

```
startActivity( new Intent(currentactivity.this, Tostartactivity.class));
```

Comment: "Or"? Referring to what? I can't see anything here that's less simple...

Answer (score 5):

You may use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClassName.class);
```

Comment: It seems if the activity is extending any activity other than `AppCompatActivity` or `Activity`, only this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

> Using `.getActivity()` solves this issue:

For eg.

```
Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this.getActivity(), Next.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You Can not Use the `Intent's Context` for Creating Intent. So You need to use your `Fragment's` `Parent Activity` `Context`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MyClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same Error was coming with my code in Activity but not in Fragment. Showing constructor error for different line like new Intent( From.this, To.class) and new ArrayList<> etc.

Fixed using closing Android Studio and moving the repository to other location and opening the the project once again. Fixed the problem.

Seems like Android Studio building problem.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
    ncharacters.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent openncharacter = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ncharacters.class);
            startActivity(openncharacter);
        }
    });
```