# How to go to a new activity from a pop up?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a pop up to confirm a package and when the user selects the "confirm" button it should take the user to another activity but it is not working properly.

Here is my code:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_solicitar:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle("Confirmación");
            builder.setMessage("¿Deseas solicitar " + sum + " toallas con un total de $" + tot1 + " pesos?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Confirmar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(Paquetes.this, "¡Tu pedido ha sido solicitado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(this, Casa.class));
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Casa.class));
```

Comment: why we need `getActivity()` in this case?

Comment: you should pass your activity context as a first parameter in your intent as stated here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20241921/5870896

Comment: in the link you share to me, it is start new activity from `Fragment` not from `Activity`

Comment: OMG! Now it works!! Thanks a lot to Phan, Rashid and incr3dible. I used the "getApplicationContext()".

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Casa.class));
```

to

```
startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this, Casa.class)); //YourActivity is the class name of your current Activity
```

Comment: @AldoT can you explain more about `didn't work`. your app crash or your can not run the app

Comment: When I do that it does not allow me to run the app, it shows an error that says "Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(java.lang.Class<Paquetes>,java.lang.Class<Casa>)'"

Comment: does the toast pops up? aldot?

Comment: incr3dible, the toast appears after the user clicks on confirm

Comment: @AldoT you say `it does not allow me to run the app. "Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(java.lang.Class<Paquetes>,java.lang.Class<Casa>)'"`, why the Toast can show :(

Comment: @AldoT both `YourActivity.this` or `getApplicationContext` will fix your problem. However, you should remember that   
`YourActivity.this refers to activity context and getApplicationContext () refers to the application context.`

Comment: @PhanVănLinh ok, I'll remember that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try ,

```
startActivity(new Intent(Paquetes.this, Casa.class));    // assuming your current activity is Paquetes
```

if it doesn't work can you post your error log once?

Answer (score 0):

Please run your application in debug mode.Check if it is stopping at startActivity(new Intent(this, Casa.class)).If not please post your logcat.

One more thing Please check your manifest:

Have you declared your Activity Casa.class in manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".Casa" >
```

If nothing is working out I request you to post your logcat.